# What is default threshold for Microsoft face api?

Tags: face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I was playing around with Microsoft [Face Api](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/face-api). When comparing two photos for facial verification, it gives out confidence score. So what is default threshold after which api identifies different match

Answer (score 3):

By default, isIdentical is set to True if similarity confidence is greater than or equal to 0.5.

This is useful for advanced users to override "isIdentical" and fine-tune the result on their own data.

Source: [Face API Reference - Verify](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523a)